# I need some ajax with jquery training sets

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm looking for "using ajax with jquery" video training sets but i can't find.
I did look lynda, killerajax etc. but i can't find..

If you know any training set, please write..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this [page "JQuery & Ajax Free Video Tutorial"](http://www.newthinktank.com/2010/05/jquery-ajax-free-video-tutorial/) can help you?